# SQL Server applying MAX and BETWEEN functions on nvarchar field

Tags: sql-server, date, max, between, nvarchar

We've got a database that's running on SQL Server 2000 DBMS, the dates and times are stored as nvarchar fields (dates are stored as shamsi dates like '1393/02/24' and times are stored as '13:07' the application is old and queries are hard coded in the application so changing the data type is not a feasible option. The tables contain hundreds of thousands of records.
A sample query on this system looks like this :

```
SELECT C1, C2, ...
FROM tbl1 WHERE ReferenceDate = '1393/02/17' 
AND PrintDate IN (SELECT MAX(PrintDate) FROM tbl2 WHERE Code = tbl1.Code)
```

There are also queries that have PrintDate BETWEEN ...

These queries are deep under 6 or 7 levels of joins so the level of recursion is high with them.

The queries are also not written in the most efficient way but since they are hardcoded, and the application is a legacy one with zero documentation available, applying changes to the queries from the application code is really really hard.

Now the issue is that this system is running really slow, some reports take more than 30 seconds to execute and some timeout and around 90% of the execution time is consumed by the sort operation and convert operation on these date fields saved as nvarchar, I applied some indexing on these fields but it didn't really help.

Is there anything that can be done to increase the performance of these queries? Does moving the database to a newer version of SQL Server like 2012 make a performance improvement?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll probably get more useful answers in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Dates stored as strings are not ideal, but if they're stored as 'YYYY/MM/DD', that's the next best thing. I would make sure the indexes are being used.

Comment: As Gabe said, learn about your database's date-time data types and use one. Then index it.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following to improve query performance:

1. Check the indexes
2. Update Statistics if required - talk to DBA regarding this
3. Review the query plan especially estimated vs actual row counts
4. Try and error with different queries doing the same job.

The first thing I would try is to use CTE or Temp Table with Index and use JOIN rather than IN.